# How to bulk delete Orders in Drupal Commerce module

Tags: commerce

I need to delete 200 Drupal commerce orders. Is there any way to do this in a bulk action?

Orders are at:   **/admin/commerce/orders**

Same with Customer profiles. I need to delete them with a bulk action. Can I accomplish with this?

Customer profiles are at:   **/admin/commerce/customer-profiles/list**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module for that™

With [Commerce VBO views](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_vbo_views) you can create a view where you can mass delete orders and products. I don't know about customer profiles, but that could be a feature request if it's not added yet.

Comment: You trademarked it! A definite +1!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that module. Just wondering... what if I just use the VBO module to add a vbo fiel to the main orders view. Is this bad practice?

Comment: @chefnelone What do you mean by a VBO field?

Comment: please, look a the image capture http://screencast.com/t/WgyeeSQyG

Comment: @chefnelone What you are talking about is not a "field" but the core functionality behind VBO which won't work without Views and is not something that is possible to add to entities like orders are.

Answer (score 6):

If you've got 65,000 orders that you need to wipe, VBO isn't an option. You can try this:

```
TRUNCATE commerce_customer_profile;
TRUNCATE commerce_customer_profile_revision;
TRUNCATE commerce_funds_transactions;
TRUNCATE commerce_funds_user_funds;
TRUNCATE commerce_line_item;
TRUNCATE commerce_order;
TRUNCATE commerce_order_revision;
TRUNCATE commerce_payment_transaction;
TRUNCATE commerce_payment_transaction_revision;
TRUNCATE commerce_paypal_ipn;

TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_customer_address;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_customer_billing;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_customer_shipping;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_line_items;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_order_total;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_price;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_product;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_shipping_service;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_total;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_unit_price;

TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_coupon_order_reference;
TRUNCATE field_data_commerce_display_path;
TRUNCATE field_data_field_order_deliveryinstructions;
TRUNCATE field_data_field_order_flags;
TRUNCATE field_data_field_order_id;
TRUNCATE field_data_field_order_notes;
TRUNCATE field_data_field_supplier;


TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_customer_address;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_customer_billing;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_customer_shipping;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_line_items;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_order_total;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_price;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_product;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_shipping_service;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_total;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_unit_price;

TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_coupon_order_reference;
TRUNCATE field_revision_commerce_display_path;
TRUNCATE field_revision_field_order_deliveryinstructions;
TRUNCATE field_revision_field_order_flags;
TRUNCATE field_revision_field_order_id;
TRUNCATE field_revision_field_order_notes;
TRUNCATE field_revision_field_supplier;
```

Comment: Manually truncating tables can cause issues in drupal if the order entities are referenced anywhere else. I'd use this on a development site but never on production.

vijaycs85's answer would probably address the performance concern.

Answer (score 2):

[Commerce Order Cleanup](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_order_cleanup) is another attempt on this front:

> Allows to cleanup the orders by various order properties like last changed, status.